# Find list length of sublist that made from list and int

Tags: python, compiler-errors, variable-length

as  per the title, how to find list length of sublist that made from list and int.
For example, give a list

```
ListNo=[[6,2,5],[3,10],4,1]
```

it should return LengthSubList 3,2,1,1.

I make the following code,

```
LengthSubList=[len(x) for x in ListNo]
```

But, compiler give the following error

```
object of type 'int' has no len()
```

May I know what I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's a list before you do `len()`:

```
ListNo = [[6,2,5],[3,10],4,1]

print([len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 1 for x in ListNo])
# [3, 2, 1, 1]
```

What you got wrong is you cannot do `len(4)` and `len(1)`, simply because it would return a `TypeError` - object of type 'int' has no len().

Answer (score 1):

Your code will call `len(4)` and `len(1)` in your list comprehension which throws the self explanatory error. Try this:

```
LengthSubList=[len(x) if type(x) == list else 1 for x in ListNo]
```